# Iframe issue: Salesforce not fetching parent in SOQL nested query

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex, salesforce-communities

**SITUATION:** Hi I have a query THAT functions well & as per expectations in salesforce vf page only.

**PROBLEM** It returns the output without its parent object when calling from an iframe.

**The code in apex:**

```
public class showServiceHistory {
CKSW_BASE__Service__c services;
String id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
String x;
public myValues()
{
    services = [SELECT id, name, (SELECT Name, Previous_Status__c, New_Status__c, Reason_Code__c, comment__c FROM Service_Status_History__r) FROM CKSW_BASE__Service__c WHERE id=:id];           
}
public String getxx()
{
    x=JSON.Serialize(services);
    return x;   
}
}
```

**The Code In VF**

```
< apex:page controller="myValues" >

< apex:pageBlock title="{!xx}" >

< /apex:pageBlock >

< /apex:page >
```

> **Output From Salesforce**
>
> `{"attributes":{"type":"CKSW_BASE__Service__c","url":"/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/CKSW_BASE__Service__c/sss"},"Id":"s","Name":"S","Service_Status_History__r":{"totalSize":6,"done":true,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Service_Status_History__c","url":"/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Service_Status_History__c/ss"},"Service__c":"asss","Id":"uu","Name":"yyy","Previous_Status__c":"xyz","New_Status__c":"y","Reason_Code__c":"xyz","Comment__c":"abc"}]}`

And

> **Output from iframe**
>
> {"attributes":{"type":"CKSW_BASE__Service__c","url":"/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/CKSW_BASE__Service__c/444"},"Id":"444","Name":"xyz"}

From the **Vf page I get the desired output with full value**, but from an **iframe in my force.com url the parent object (nested query) is not available**.

However, when I **call only parent** with a simple **dedicated query**, it **returns the value** in **both(iframe and url)** places.

*WHY MY NESTED SOQL IS UNABLE TO GET THE PARENT OBJECT. WHAT I AM MISSING HERE??*

Thanks in advance.
Please help.

Output from Iframe

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your FLS?

> Build -> Develop -> Sites ->  -> Public Access Settings

This is the culprit most of the times on Force.com outcome.

Answer (score 0):

> > Yes I already checked, It granted public access. And even I am able to
> >     see them when converting and printing in JSON format. But I can't see
> >     them in iframe if printed with parse object form.
>
> Hence it worked for me by sending values in Json string format and by
>   parsing it over there.

In Vf page

```
<apex:page Controller="showServiceHistory" sidebar="false" showheader="false">
<html>
    <head>
    <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20" ></meta> -->

</head>
<a id="history_data" style="display:none;">{!history}</a>
<a id="service_data" style="display:none">{!service}</a>
<style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    table,
    th,
    td {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        color: #3088D0;
    }

    th,
    td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        color: #1F497D;
    }

    tr {
        //color: #337AB7;
    }

    table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #DCE6F1;
        //color: #337AB7;
    }

    table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    table#t01 th {
        background-color: #B8CCE4;
        //color: #000015;
    }

    a:link {
        color: #62B3E2;
    }

    a:visited {
        color: #62B3E2;
    }
</style>


<table id="t01">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>

            <th>
                Previous Status
            </th>
            <th>
                New Status
            </th>
            <th>
                Comment
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="show_values">
    </tbody>

</table>
<script>
    function x()
    {
    var history={}; var service={};
    history=JSON.parse(document.getElementById("history_data").innerHTML); 
    service=JSON.parse(document.getElementById("service_data").innerHTML); 
    var show='';
        for(var i=0;i<history.length;i++)
        {
           show=show+'<tr><td>'+history[i].Name+'</td><td>'+history[i].Previous_Status__c+'</td><td>'+history[i].New_Status__c+'</td><td>'+history[i].Comment__c+'</td><td>'+service.CKSW_BASE__Location__c+'</td></tr>';
        }
            document.getElementById("show_values").innerHTML=document.getElementById("show_values").innerHTML+show;
    }
    x();
</script>
</html>
```

In apex code page

```
public class showServiceHistory {
List<Service_Status_History__c> histories;
String x;
CKSW_BASE__Service__c services;
String id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
 public showServiceHistory()
{
    services = [SELECT CKSW_BASE__Resource__c, CKSW_BASE__Location__c, (SELECT Name, Previous_Status__c, New_Status__c, comment__c FROM Service_Status_History__r) FROM CKSW_BASE__Service__c WHERE id=:id];         
    histories = services.Service_Status_History__r;
}
public String getService()
{
    return JSON.Serialize(services);   
}
public String getHistory()
{
    return JSON.Serialize(histories);
}
```

}